# Install using pip a specific module

Tags: python

I try to install rpy2 using pip.

I user windows 10.

I run the pip command in cmd console with admin option

However I receive this error:

pip install rpy2

> ```
>  Collecting rpy2
>       Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/e0/7da849bb6cf47466ceb28a75f930e61c311878882c275dfb4bbb4fdcc3cb/rpy2-3.2.0.tar.gz
>         ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>          command: 'c:\users\mary\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe'
> ```
>
> -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Mary\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2\setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Mary\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
>                    cwd: C:\Users\Mary\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2\
>               Complete output (79 lines):
>               test_pw_r.c
>               C:\Users\Mary\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_pw_r_b9t41l4r\test_pw_r.c(1):
>   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Rinterface.h': No such
>   file or directory
>               warning: no previously-included files found matching 'setup.pyc'
>               warning: no previously-included files matching 'yacctab.*' found under directory 'tests'
>               warning: no previously-included files matching 'lextab.*' found under directory 'tests'
>               warning: no previously-included files matching 'yacctab.*' found under directory 'examples'
>               warning: no previously-included files matching 'lextab.*' found under directory 'examples'
>               zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
>               pycparser.ply.**pycache**.lex.cpython-37: module references **file**
>               pycparser.ply.**pycache**.lex.cpython-37: module MAY be using inspect.getsourcefile
>               pycparser.ply.**pycache**.yacc.cpython-37: module references **file**
>               pycparser.ply.**pycache**.yacc.cpython-37: module MAY be using inspect.getsourcefile
>               pycparser.ply.**pycache**.yacc.cpython-37: module MAY be using inspect.stack
>               pycparser.ply.**pycache**.ygen.cpython-37: module references **file**
>
> ```
>         Installed c:\users\mary\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2\.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg
>         Traceback (most recent call last):
>           File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win32.egg\cffi\cparser.py",
> ```
>
> line 294, in _parse
>                   ast = _get_parser().parse(fullcsource)
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg\pycparser\c_parser.py",
>   line 152, in parse
>                   debug=debuglevel)
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg\pycparser\ply\yacc.py",
>   line 331, in parse
>                   return self.parseopt_notrack(input, lexer, debug, tracking, tokenfunc)
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg\pycparser\ply\yacc.py",
>   line 1061, in parseopt_notrack
>                   lookahead = get_token()     # Get the next token
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg\pycparser\c_lexer.py",
>   line 77, in token
>                   self.last_token = self.lexer.token()
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg\pycparser\ply\lex.py",
>   line 386, in token
>                   newtok = self.lexerrorf(tok)
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg\pycparser\c_lexer.py",
>   line 484, in t_error
>                   self._error(msg, t)
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg\pycparser\c_lexer.py",
>   line 93, in _error
>                   self.error_func(msg, location[0], location[1])
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg\pycparser\c_parser.py",
>   line 193, in _lex_error_func
>                   self._parse_error(msg, self._coord(line, column))
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg\pycparser\plyparser.py", line 67, in _parse_error
>                   raise ParseError("%s: %s" % (coord, msg))
>               pycparser.plyparser.ParseError: :492:96: Illegal character '\r'
>
> ```
>         During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
>         Traceback (most recent call last):
>           File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>           File "C:\Users\Mary\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2\setup.py",
> ```
>
> line 182, in 
>                   'rpy2/rinterface_lib/R_API_eventloop.h'])],
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools__init__.py",
>   line 145, in setup
>                   return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\core.py",
>   line 108, in setup
>                   _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py",
>   line 444, in **init**
>                   k: v for k, v in attrs.items()
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py",
>   line 292, in **init**
>                   self.finalize_options()
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py",
>   line 732, in finalize_options
>                   ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win32.egg\cffi\setuptools_ext.py",
>   line 217, in cffi_modules
>                   add_cffi_module(dist, cffi_module)
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win32.egg\cffi\setuptools_ext.py",
>   line 49, in add_cffi_module
>                   execfile(build_file_name, mod_vars)
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win32.egg\cffi\setuptools_ext.py",
>   line 25, in execfile
>                   exec(code, glob, glob)
>                 File "rpy2/_rinterface_cffi_build.py", line 164, in 
>                   ffibuilder_api = createbuilder_api()
>                 File "rpy2/_rinterface_cffi_build.py", line 157, in createbuilder_api
>                   ffibuilder.cdef(cdef)
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win32.egg\cffi\api.py", line 112, in cdef
>                   self._cdef(csource, override=override, packed=packed, pack=pack)
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win32.egg\cffi\api.py", line 126, in _cdef
>                   self._parser.parse(csource, override=override, **options)
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win32.egg\cffi\cparser.py",
>   line 347, in parse
>                   self._internal_parse(csource)
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win32.egg\cffi\cparser.py",
>   line 352, in _internal_parse
>                   ast, macros, csource = self._parse(csource)
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win32.egg\cffi\cparser.py",
>   line 296, in _parse
>                   self.convert_pycparser_error(e, csource)
>                 File "c:\users\mary\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-bov9dean\rpy2.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win32.egg\cffi\cparser.py",
>   line 325, in convert_pycparser_error
>                   raise CDefError(msg)
>               cffi.CDefError: cannot parse "void __cffi_extern_python_start; void _capsule_finalizer(SEXP); void __cffi_extern_python_stop;"
>               :492:96: Illegal character '\r'
>               ----------------------------------------
>           ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Any idea please what should I fix?

What is egg_info ?

Is an alternative option to install it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there happens to be a cache issue. Have you installed the package before ? If yes then try to uninstall the package and then try reinstalling it once.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to unistall rpy2 but it is not exist

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you need the R libraries. It Should work using anaconda.
First install anaconda (see https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/)
Then you install running from the anaconda console.

```
conda install rpy2
```

The difference is that it will take care of the dependencies.
See last and most recent answer in: [Installing rpy2 for Python 3 using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955491/installing-rpy2-for-python-3-using-pip)