# rpy2 version 2.9.4 installation error using conda

Tags: python, r, anaconda, rpy2

Trying to install `rpy2` (version `2.9.4`) using anaconda, facing error of `python version unsatisfied` (when `python==3.8.3` or anything over `python==3.7.1`).

When I tried same using `pip install`, facing error of `egg-info`.

Also tried installing `rpy2` version `2.9.4` on virtual kernel using pip with python(`3.7.1`), `rpy2` version is as specified but `r-base` (dependency) is of higher version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing rpy2 for Python 3 using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955491/installing-rpy2-for-python-3-using-pip)

Comment: rpy2 2.9.4 is old. You'll face an increasingly large number of problems when trying to install it with Python and R releases that did not exist when it was written. Try using a more recent rpy2 release.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. i tried shifting to rpy2 3.3.1 but it gives an error with respect to installing packages in r and throws an unlink error  ( R[write to console]: Error in unlink(f) : 3 arguments passed to .Internal(unlink) which requires 4)